# Mobile browsers + remove input field value text highlighting when focused?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple form with one input field.  I set focus on this field via javascript inputID.focus().  When testing in some android devices (and browser user-agents), I've noticed that the input value has a blue background color when given focus.  I've tried lots of things and can't seem to remove this highlighting.  Any suggestions?  Below is what I've tried:

[image]

**CSS:**

```
input { width: 200px; height: 24px; border: 1px solid #999; border-radius: 5px; font: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #666; padding: 2px; font-size: 12pt; margin-bottom: 10px; background-color: #fff !important; }
input[type=text]:focus{ border:1px solid #090; backface-visibility:hidden !important; background-color:#fff !important; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:#fff !important; -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden !important; text-decoration:none; }
input::selection { background-color:#fff; color:#fff; }
input::-moz-selection { background-color:#fff; color:#fff; }
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {background-color:#fff; color:#fff;}
input:-moz-placeholder {background-color:#fff; color:#fff;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="ducks" type="text" value="quack quack quack mr.duckworth" readonly="">
```

**Javascript:**

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('ducks');
inputBox.focus();
```

Comment: Have you tried input::-webkit-selection ? I think most android browsers are webkit. Maybe the base selector isn't covering them?

Comment: I added this... no help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh so I simply needed to set user-select on the input:focus selector:

**CSS:**

```
input[type="text"]:focus { 
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, looks like the whole input content is being selected when focused.
You may try to place the caret at the end of input filed assigning this onfocus to your input filed

```
onfocus="this.value = this.value;"
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by this suggestion. Can you clarify perhaps?

Comment: @worked The idea is that when the value of an input is changed, the input field loses its selection, if any.

Comment: I wasn't losing selection, I was gaining it unnecessarily.  I've added the correct answer above.  No need for additional inline javascript.